# LinearLayout element overlaps another

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an issue with one of my linearLayout ImageView's overlapping another linearLayout's Button. Would anyone have an idea how to have elements one on top of the other with no Overlap? i've tried `android:layout_above="@+id/overlappedButton"` but the imageView still overlaps my LinearLayout's button. Here is my code, there should be three buttons under the second imageview, but for now there is only one that is visible. Thanks in advance.

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/fragment_splash"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/black"
android:gravity="center"
android:paddingLeft="0dp"
android:paddingRight="0dp"
android:layout_marginTop="0dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/gherboicon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:src="@drawable/splash_icon"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/gherbo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:src="@drawable/splash_pic"
    android:layout_above="@+id/splash_screen_buttons"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/splash_screen_buttons"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="invisible">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sign_up_splash"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_login_red"
        android:onClick="signup"
        android:text="Sign Up"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login_splash"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_login_white"
        android:onClick="login"
        android:text="@string/btn_signin"
        android:textColor="@drawable/txt_login_white" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/skip_now_splash"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:onClick="skipNow"
        android:text="Skip for now"
        android:textColor="@color/charcoal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: where is the closing tag of root linearlayout

Comment: try resizing your imageviews, maybe they're too big for your screen.

Comment: or put them inside `scrollView`

Comment: Use a `RelativeLayout` or `ConstraintLayout`

Answer (score 0):

Use the following architecture in your xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout
    <LinearLayout>
        <ImageView/>
        <ImageView/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayoutOne">
        <Button/>
        <Button/>
        <Button/>
   </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

After wrapping both of your linearLayouts into a relative layout, you will be able to create a relationship behavior by putting your second LinearLayout below your first one.

Answer (score 0):

Add ScrollView to make the LinearLayout Scrollable

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/fragment_splash"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
android:background="@android:color/black"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingLeft="0dp"
android:paddingRight="0dp">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/gherboicon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:src="@drawable/splash_icon"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/gherbo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/splash_screen_buttons"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/splash_pic"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/splash_screen_buttons"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="invisible">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/sign_up_splash"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_login_red"
                android:onClick="signup"
                android:text="Sign Up"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/login_splash"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_login_white"
                android:onClick="login"
                android:text="@string/btn_signin"
                android:textColor="@drawable/txt_login_white" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/skip_now_splash"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:onClick="skipNow"
                android:text="Skip for now"
                android:textColor="@color/charcoal" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```